# enable auto-completion for C in Mono Develop

Tags: c, mono, autocomplete, monodevelop, ctags

I need to enable Auto completion for C programs in Mono - I think using CTAG?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Quick google found me this ( I had the same question )

Open Edit->Preferences, go to Other->C/C++, then check "Parse system tags" and "Parse local variables".

As mhutch says, you also need to install ctags.

Comment: These only enable advanced completion - the basics require ctags to be installed.